# URI is accessible and downloadable from browser, but slurp/reader returns an empty vector

Tags: csv, clojure

I am new to Clojure, and I am trying to read a set of data from Yahoo's historical finance API. I've used slurp and reader on other URIs which seem to be fine, but I seem to be unable to read this specific one.

The problem URI: http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=WU&a=11&b=15&c=2016&d=11&e=19&f=2016&g=d&ignore=.csv

Accessing this from the browser results in a CSV file with data in it, but slurp/reader returns an empty vector. I've tried:

```
(def uri-string
  (str "http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csvs=WU&a=11&b=15&c=2016&d=11&e=19&f=2016&g=d&ignore=.csv"))
(slurp uri-string)
```

and:

```
(with-open [rdr (clojure.java.io/reader "http://ichart.finance.yahoo.com/table.csv?s=WU&a=11&b=15&c=2016&d=11&e=19&f=2016&g=d&ignore=.csv")] (reduce conj [] (line-seq rdr)))
```

but neither work. Anyone have any ideas on how to proceed, or what the problem is here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try `curl -v 'http://...'`. It's pretty clear from this that yahoo is redirecting your HTTP traffic to HTTPS instead. Your browser handles this automatically, but slurp is a very basic tool. You will have to use something fancier than slurp if you want to actually navigate the web. An HTTP client like https://github.com/dakrone/clj-http will have a way for you to configure how it responds to redirects.

Comment: I just dug through the URI with clj-http, and it is exactly as you said. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @amalloy you might want to write this in an answer so this stop showing up as "unanswered".